# Can't get my own photos with FlickrNet

Tags: c#, asp.net, flickr

I'm using FlickrNet-api-nuget. And trying to only get my own photos (all photos are public on the flicker.com site)
But the only thing it keeps returning is som random pictures that I don't want.
All I want is my own pictures. I'm doing it like this, but something must be wrong:

```
public static FlickrNet.Flickr GetInstance()
{
    return new FlickrNet.Flickr(ApiKey, SharedSecret);
}

var options = new PhotoSearchOptions { PerPage = 2, Page = 1, UserId ="myUserId"};
PhotoCollection photos = FlickrManager.GetInstance().PhotosSearch(options);
```

What is wrong here? I try to specify a specific user, but omnly getting som other random photos. All I want is my own photos from flick

Comment: Your code works for me. Are you sure you have the correct user id. Are you getting more than one users photos back?

Comment: @CathalMF Iv'e used this link to find the user Id: http://idgettr.com/

Comment: @CathalMF Where can I find my user Id? If the link I provided maybe calculates wrong

Comment: Just sign into your account, select one of your photos and look at the URL. Your userid is the number in the url with an @ symbol.